# hide the yellow dots on overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I click, the link the modal opens up, but when the modal opens, there is a black background color. Along with that, yellow dots appear. I don't want the yellow dots to be shown on the overlay.

http://jsfiddle.net/y88WX/18/embedded/result/

```
<nav class="da-dots"><span></span><span></span><span></span></nav>

.da-dots {
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
left: 0px;
bottom: 20px;
z-index: 2000;
-moz-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: You should reduce their z-index.

Comment: that JSFiddle totally froze my browser, scripts became unresponsive and I had to restart it. FF 18 and 19.

Comment: can you check it in chrome

Comment: I'm in chrome and no freeze but I also don't see your supposed black background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the z-index of .da-dots  from 2000 to 100 ( or some value you like, but it should lower than the layer has)

The rule is defined in style2.css. 
Suggestion : You should modify the z-index in your style2.css file.

```
.da-dots {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2000; /* change to 100 */
}
```

If you are not able to edit style2.css, you can define this in your body

```
<style>
.da-dots { 
    z-index: 100 !important; 
    /* You can remove !important if you able to edit style2.css*/
}
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y88WX/21/embedded/result/